# Using each() to iterate through multiple ul's and hiding any child li's greater than 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need a bit of help understanding how to iterate through all ul elements with a class of ul.children and hide any of the child elements under ul.child greater than 8.

example of my code below:

```
$(function() {
$('ul.children').each(function() {
    var $ul = $(this);
    if($ul.children().length > 8) {
        $ul.hide();
    } 
});
});
```

example of my html code:

```
<ul class="children>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>hide all other li elements below this point</li>
</ul>

<ul class="children>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>hide all other li elements below this point</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**gt()**](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to filter the elements having index greater than 8.

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vLjJT/2/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.children').each(function () {        
        $('li:gt(8)', this).hide();        
    });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I was using gt() last night but obviously in the wrong way - I'm guessing it would be pretty simple to append a see all categories link from there. Going to do it now.

Comment: Did i do that? Apologies if i did.

Comment: You did not do it @TomChampion. Thanks for care.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("ul.children").find("li:gt(7)").hide();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7TtKD/

---

Or another solution suggested by [@Vitaliy Petrychuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425086/using-each-to-iterate-through-multiple-uls-and-hiding-any-child-lis-greater/14425097#comment20079381_14425097) in the comments:

```
$(".children > li:nth-child(n+9)").hide();
```

Comment: or this way `$('.children > li:nth-child(1n + 9)').hide();`

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk Yes. There is even no need in `1` before `n`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use index() and toggle() :

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.children li').each(function(i,ele) {
        $(ele).toggle($(ele).index() > 7);
    });
});
```

Comment: @roasted - you are indeed correct, toggle() IS deprecated, but there are two versions of toggle(), and this is not the one that is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `filter()` method:

http://jsfiddle.net/HZ3LE/

```
$('ul.children li').filter(function(i){return i>7}).hide();
```